# What is the standard notation for reversing the order of vector's components?

Tags: notation

If we have a vector $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$, is there any standard way to denote the vector $(x_n,x_{n-1},\ldots,x_1)$?.

I think that $x^{-1}$ could be a good option.

Comment: For a permutation of indices $\sigma$, I would denote  $x_\sigma:=(x_{\sigma_1},\dots x_{\sigma_n})$, (or $x\sigma$ or $x\circ\sigma$ or   $x^\sigma$).

Comment: @PietroMajer: And how do you denote the permutation $\sigma(i)=n+1-i$ of $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$?

Comment: My 2c: how about $x^\leftarrow$?

Comment: @ HeinrichD, yes, this is the question

Comment: Instead of $x$, name your vector $b$ and the reversed one $d$.

Comment: @monkeymaths or a and ɐ

Comment: This also depends on the choice of basis for your vector space.

Comment: @LorenoHeer This is certainly the appropriate choice when referring to column-vectors.

Comment: What's the application you have in mind?

Answer (score 10):

An alternative would be to define and use the **exchange matrix** (see the [Wikipedia entry “Exchange matrix”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix))
$$
  J = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 &\cdots &0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 &\cdots & 0 &0\\
1 & 0 &\cdots & 0 &0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and to note that $(x_n, \dotsc, x_1)=J (x_1, \dotsc, x_n)$.

Answer (score 5):

I think that $\mathrm{flip}(x)$ is a better choice. This is also used in some programming languages. Notice that $x^{-1}$ could be easily confused with $(x_1^{-1},\dotsc,x_n^{-1})$.

Comment: Hm, actually, just $\mathrm{reverse}$ seems to be more common. See e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/reverse/